# E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack Android studio

Tags: android, logcat

I have an issue with lower api I tasted my app on 15, 19 and 22 api the crashes on start the only ones works are 24 and above api I don't know why my app is just Math calculations .I searched a lot to find answer for last 2 days and I tried myriad of thing none of them work for me. Here is my full logcat error and code.Thanks for any help.

```
E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1144: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004               
(EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read- 
only file system
? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.slltour.desar.electricalcalculator, PID: 6967
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070066
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.setViewImage(SimpleAdapter.java:262)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:192)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayE
```

//**Here is my main code**

```
    private int[] tabIcons = {   
    R.drawable.ic_home_tab,
    R.drawable.ic_library_books_black_24dp,
    R.drawable.calu_tab_icon,R.drawable.conv_tab_icon,
    R.drawable.question_tab_icon};
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TabAdapter adapter;
    Animation  btnanim ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.all_tabs);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new tab1_fragment(), "Tb1");
        adapter.addFragment(new tab2_fragment(), "Tb2");
        adapter.addFragment(new tab3_fragment(), "Tb3");
        adapter.addFragment(new tab4_fragment(), "Tb4");
        adapter.addFragment(new tab5_fragment(), "Tb5");
        btnanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.btnanim);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);
        }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.slltour.desar.electricalcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update*** it was a cake ;) after 3 days ;(.

Just move ur PNG and icons to **'Drawable'** Folder instead of **'Drawable-24'** !!